# Build Application to Answer Phone Call and Delegate To iPhone's Phone Application

Tags: iphone

We want to build an application that the user can interact with while taking a phone call.  The idea is that the user can do voice communication using the phone application of the iPhone and at the same time use our application to type and send additional data that is relevant to the call such as an e-mail address.  This is the scenario:

1. User get's a call on the iPhone
2. The user clicks a button on our app to answer the call and let the phone application on the iPhone handle the phone call in the background.
3. Our application continues to run in the foreground so that the user can interact with our application to type and send data such as an e-mail address that is relevant to the call.

Is there a way for our application to answer an incoming phone call and let the phone application of the iPhone handle the call in the background while our application continues to run in the foreground?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: If this question no longer requires additional answers, please mark the appropriate post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the iOS SDK does not support redirecting incoming calls from the system to a custom application. There is only support for initiating a call.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the iPhone SDK.

You could possibly do this if you created your own calling (for example, like Skype does) but I'd say you're barking up the wrong iTree here. It is however possible on jail-broken devices using the custom toolchain but I wouldn't want to recommend that path for development!

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over the phone call process on an iPhone (this is assuming that you’re not talking about a jailbroken iPhone). When the user receives a call, the iPhone presents a window with the number and the “Answer” and “Ignore” buttons (or, if the phone is locked or asleep, the “Slide to Answer” bar). To return to your or any other application, the user must press the home button, sending the call to the background (and activating the red in-call status bar).

The closest you’ll get to this scenario is the user manually running the application while on the phone. But then, if all they’re doing is writing notes, they could just use the Notes app.

Comment: Which means that the need for an application isn't there ;)

Comment: Well, I was *trying* to be nice about it… ;-)

Comment: Hehe, yea. I've heard stories of Apps being rejected on the basis that they're pointless. +1 Anyways