# Can an iOS app answer a phone call?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

I'm actually re-asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314766/build-application-to-answer-phone-call-and-delegate-to-iphones-phone-applicatio) question. I thought after 3 years there might have been a change in the public API after the introduction of iOS 7. My guess is 'no' but I'm not a iOS dev.

Comment: Allowing the app to *actually answer* calls would be fantastic for combating unwanted telemarketing with your own robot like this answering service does: http://www.jollyrogertelco.com/ (no affiliation--just think it's an awesome and hilarious service).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct, you still cant

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something Apple will not want developers to start messing with, I do believe that anything to do with answering phone calls are part of private APIs which if used will be rejected by Apple instantly and apps that mimic Apps bundled with the iPhone will be rejected.

I believe that any app that does this would be rejected under one of the two below reasons from the Apple App Store review

> 2.5 - Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
>
> 10.2 - Apps that look similar to Apps bundled on the iPhone, including the App Store, iTunes Store, and iBookstore, will be rejected

Sorry :-(

Comment: Brings up a good point. It's not possible and will probably never be.

Answer (score -1):

No, its not possible. Apple forbitts it beacause of security reasons.

Comment: Whilst I do agree that it isn't possible do you have anything more then just "because of security reasons"? What security reasons?

Comment: If app could answer a phone call without user supervision it could answer paid services and that would cost a user a lot. Sending and reading SMS is similar in that matter.

Comment: Except reverse charges what service charges you to receive phone calls or SMS messages? Please can you provide some source to your answer.

Comment: what about the fact that we can programmatically dial numbers? thats a much bigger risk and easier for a scammer to profit from. dialing a number from an app feel instrusive vs. e.g. an app to record phone conversations for you, or act as a loud speaker style answer phone so you can screen your calls...